# Passing UUID as Input parameter to a trigger function - Postgres 11.5

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in this format

```
  CREATE TABLE Responses (
    Responseid uuid NOT NULL,
    Response jsonb NOT NULL,
    createdtime timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

The ResponseID is generated by the uuid_generate function. I want to create a trigger function on this table as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_Response() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $get_Response$
DECLARE 
    ResponseName VARCHAR(100);    
BEGIN

    select into ResponseName Response->>'ResponseName' 
    from Responses
    where Responseid =uuid;
 IF (ResponseName = 'ABC') then
 -----------
 elseif (ResponseName = 'ABC') then 
 ------------------
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$get_Queue_Info$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER get_Response
AFTER INSERT  ON Responses
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION get_Response();
```

Can you please suggest how to pass that uuid into the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the up to date values using the `NEW` keyword. To get the `Responseid` field, you would use `NEW.Responseid`

```sql
select into ResponseName Response->>'ResponseName' 
from Responses
where Responseid = NEW.uuid;
```

But since you have access to the entire record, you don't need to re-select it. You can directly query the `response` field

```sql
select into ResponseName NEW.Response->>'ResponseName'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JGH. that helped